# Pass parameters to custom messages defined in .isl files

Tags: inno-setup

My update has to figure out if two known files exist in the directory the user has specified. If not I want to let him know, that there are no files at this path. Up to now, this was a `CustomMessage` in all of my .isl Files.
Now I want to show him the complete path he entered with the files.

Up to now the message looks like this:

> File1, File2 or both could not be found at the selected location....

What I now want is this:

> %1, %2 or both could not be found...

For `%1` and `%2` I want to pass in the complete specified paths, but I cannot see how to do this. `ExpandConstant` does not have any arguments, and up to now I've found nothing about how to pass parameters to a custom message.

To clarify things, here's the code:

```pascal
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
  ServerData : String;
  UseDatabase : String;
  Language : String;
  ResultCode : Integer;
  ExePath : String;
  ConfigFilePath : String;
begin
  Result := True;
  if CurPageID = wpSelectDir then begin
    if DirExists(ExpandConstant('{app}')) then begin
        MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{app}'),mbInformation,MB_OK);    
        UpdatePath := ExpandConstant('{app}');
        ExePath := UpdatePath+'\File1.exe';
        ConfigFilePath := UpdatePath+'\File2.exe.config'; 
        if FileExists(UpdatePath+'\File1.exe') and FileExists(UpdatePath+'\File2.exe.config') then begin
            RegPath := UpdatePath;
            UpdatePath := RegPath + '\Update-' + ExpandConstant('{#MyAppVersion}');
            ConfigPath := RegPath + '\File2.exe.config';
            DBPage.Values[0] := ExtractServerAddr(GetServerData(ConfigPath));
            DBPage.Values[1] := ExtractServerPort(GetServerData(ConfigPath));           
        end else begin
            MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:DirPageFileNotFound,ExePath,ConfigFilePath}'),mbInformation,MB_OK);
            Result := False;
        end;
    end else begin
            MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:DirPageDirectoryNotFound}'),mbInformation,MB_OK);
            Result := False;
    end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pascal Script you should use [`CustomMessage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_custommessage) together with [`FmtMessage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_fmtmessage):

```pascal
FmtMessage(CustomMessage('DirPageFileNotFound'), [ExePath, ConfigFilePath])
```

---

It's cleaner and less error prone than assembling the `{cm:MessageName,Arguments}` ["constant"](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts). [Your syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33755121/850848#33757680) will for example break, if there's any comma or curly bracket in any of the paths.

The `{cm:...}` constant is intended for use in non-`Code` sections, like:

```
[Run]
Filename: "myapp.exe"; Description: "{cm:RunningApp,myapp.exe}";
```

---

Similar question: [Pass parameters to custom messages defined in .isl files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33755121/850848)

Comment: And that's something I didn't knew that it existed. Thanks for showing me that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution is as easy as it could possibly be:

```pascal
ToExpand := '{cm:DirPageFileNotFound,' + ExePath +',' + ConfigFilePath + '}'
MsgBox(ExpandConstant(ToExpand),mbInformation,MB_OK);
```

This two lines did the trick.

PS: I'm thankful for StackOverflow being my rubber duck.