# How can I use language files with custom messages with preprocessor constants?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to have all `CustomMessages` in language files (extension `isl`). Also, some of the messages contain preprocessor constants, e.g.

```
ALREADY_INSTALLED={#MyAppName} is already installed on this computer.
```

The message should be displayed like this:

> "My-really-nice-App is already installed on this computer"

But what I get is:

> "{#MyAppName} is already installed on this computer."

The following works like a charm when I have the code, the message defined in a `[CustomMessages]`-topic  and `#define MyAppName` in the same iss file:

```pascal
MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:ALREADY_INSTALLED}'), ...);
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only `.iss` file is preprocessed, not `.isl` files.

But you can use [`FmtMessage` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_fmtmessage):

```pascal
FmtMessage(CustomMessage('ALREADY_INSTALLED'), ['{#MyAppName}'])
```

With

```
ALREADY_INSTALLED=%1 is already installed on this computer.
```

Note that in Pascal Script code, you better use [`CustomMessage('FOO')`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_custommessage), instead of `ExpandConstant('{cm:FOO}')`.

---

Similar question: [Pass parameters to custom messages defined in .isl files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33755121/850848).

If you need to preprocess the standard messages, see [Can I use .isl files for the messages with preprocessor directives in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64932221/850848)